# simulator not showing after successfull build in xcode 4.6.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I have updated my Xcode to 4.6.1 OS X 10.8.4.But when I am running any downloaded projects or creating my own,the build is happening successfully but the simulator is not showing,but in the schemes I have selected the simulator.

Please fix this issue.

Comment: Is it showing any error message ?

Comment: You probably haven't specified a build target

Answer (score 0):

ok does the simulator appear.if yes please select IOS simulator in toolbar and then 'Reset Content and Settings'.I suppose this should work and if there is the case that simulator is itself not appearing then please quit xcode and work.
I suppose it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Exit out from the XCODE and run the project again. there should not be any problem in running the project on simulator. also are you trying to run a native iOS project or Phonegap project?